# How come an input date only seems to fire the function once you've clicked out of the input?

Tags: javascript, html, date, events, input

I have a form that takes in a user's input of a date. My goal is that as soon as the date goes from being an empty string to actually being filled, the bottom section (in order to continue filling out the form) would show. I've succeeded in making this possible however the function only seems to run once the user has clicked out of the input. I am hoping to make it so the user doesn't have to click out and it would run as soon as the input date value is changed. I am using Chrome at the moment, which hasn't given me a problem yet.

I have tried using addEventListener with change and the function, I have tried other html dom events such as onchange, oninput, onfocus etc. but they all seem to only run once the user has clicked out. My next attempt is to jerry rig it and do a set timeout with focus... what are your thoughts?

JS and HTML

```js
function inputTodayDate(){

  let inputDate = document.getElementById("today");
  let todayRecord = document.getElementById('date').value;

  if ( todayRecord === '') {
  inputDate.style.display = "none";}
  else{
    inputDate.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="date" id='date' onfocus="inputTodayDate"> <label for='date' > Today's Date </label>
<p>
<div id="today">
<input type="amount" size=25 Placeholder="How much did you spend today?" id="spent" name="today" required>
<select id="moneySpent" onchange='checkOnWhat(this.value);' name="today" required>
  <option> Groceries</option>
  <option>Going out</option>
  <option>Bills</option>
  <option>Other</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="whatOn" id="whatOn" style='display:none;' name="today" required />
<p>
  <input type="button" value="confirm" onClick="deductFromTotal()" name="today">

  <h3 name="today"> Today's Spending: </h3>
  <div id="listTotalSpent" name="today"></div>
  <h2 id="totalSpent" name="today"></h2>

<p>
<input type='button' value= 'record' onClick= "storeWhen(); inputTodayDate()" name="today">
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't use the same value for *name* and *id* across multiple elements. The reasons are historic.

Comment: Noted, thanks for that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the mouseup and keyup events to achieve this..

```
let $inputField = document.getElementById("date");
let callback = function () {
  let inputDate = document.getElementById("today");
  let todayRecord = document.getElementById('date').value;

  if ( todayRecord === '') {
  inputDate.style.display = "none";}
  else{
    inputDate.style.display = "block";
  }
}
$inputField.oninput= callback;
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onkeyup' of null
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onmouseup' of null

This code brought back these errors...

Comment: Oh make sure you run the script after your html is loaded. So either add the script tag at the end of your html, or wrap the javascript code in the following:

Comment: `window.onload = function () { /* code from my answer goes here */ }`

Why? It cant set the property on $inputField, because when we tried to get is through its element id, it didnt existed yet. Because the browser hadn't loaded into the DOM yet. Placing the javscript in the piece of code above, we make sure the script is runned only after the entire HTML is loaded in the browser.

Also, i updated my answer, since the `input` event is way better for this.

Comment: I ended up doing something really simple, I just moved the Script to the bottom right before the </body> tag and the oninput worked. Like you said the DOM needed to load first! Your input helped me solve this issue! Thank you very much!

Comment: Great! Did you end up using the `input` event? Maybe you could then accept my answer, would give me some digital credits :)

Comment: Sorry didn't go online for a bit! Just accepted your answer! Thanks for your help!